# Good documentation for Antlr in C/C++

Tags: antlr

Where can I find good documentation to use Antlr in C/C++?
I've the Definitive Antlr reference book, but it only explains things in Java.

Thanks

Ajay

Comment: Are you required to use Antlr? There are other C++ parser frameworks that may be more suitable and have extensive documentation like boost::spirit http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 2):

There is some useful stuff up on the Antlr website. This article in particular may be helpful to you:

http://www.antlr.org/api/C/index.html

Comment: Not really.  The documentation for the ANTLR C backend is terrible -- most of it just lists function names and parameters with maybe a single-sentence description of what the function does if you're lucky.  The maintainer's stock answer to any queries about documentation is basically "read the source code".  Thanks, Mr Idle (not an insult, that is his name).

Answer (score 1):

*Definitive Antlr* has this recommendation in a footnote to the `language` option, on page 105:

> "See
>   http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets
>   for the latest information about ANTLR
>   language targets."

This leads to a long list of languages for which Antlr support is complete or in development. The C row links to the [Antlr/C wiki entry](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR3+Code+Generation+-+C), which provides status, strategy, supported platforms, and a link to [usage documentation](http://www.antlr.org/api/C/index.html).

Disclaimer: I've used Antlr only with the Java language option.